# Is my interpretation of Rotation Matrices correct?

Tags: vector-analysis, rotations

I've been asked to find the matrix which rotates vector $\vec{V}$ by angle $\alpha$ in the x-y plane. This I understand and I've constructed the matrix:

$R_{\alpha}=
\begin{bmatrix}
cos\alpha & -sin\alpha & 0\\ sin\alpha & cos\alpha & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\ \end{bmatrix}$

The next part confuses me though. I'm told to rotate my axes (not my vector) by an angle $\alpha$ around the $z$ axis. Once this has been achieved, then I have to rotate my vector by an angle $\beta$ on the x'-z' plane.

The way I'd do this is to find $R_{\alpha}^T$ where $R_\alpha$ is the matrix defined above. This new matrix rotates my axes. From here, to have the rotation on the x'-z' plane I define the next matrix as:

$R_{x'-z'} =
\begin{bmatrix}
-sin\alpha & 0 & cos\alpha \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ cos\alpha & 0 & sin\alpha \\ \end{bmatrix}$

This might look odd and as if I've mistaken where the sines and cosines go, but if we remember the convention for rotation then it's OK.

So, am I right? Is rotating my axes the same as using the transpose of $R_\alpha$ ? If yes, could you maybe tell me why so?

How should axes be rotated if I'm wrong then?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the question verbatim? It would be easier to understand then through your explanation as you work it out.

Comment: The thing is the question is in spanish. And everybody in class complained to the professor that the question was badly-put, and he gave an explanation similar to what I've included in the text :/.

Comment: I'm mostly interested in my reasoning with the transpose matrix. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Your $R_{\alpha}$ matrix looks like your rotation matrix for rotation around $z$ the second question since the rotation matrix is $$ \begin{bmatrix} x'\cdot x & x'\cdot y & x'\cdot z\\y'\cdot x & y'\cdot y & y'\cdot z\\z'\cdot x & z'\cdot y & z'\cdot z\end{bmatrix}$$ where $'$ indicate new axes. Since $z$ doesn't change, $z=z'$. Then one usually applies $R^{\intercal}TR$ to the vector or matrix.